# how to extract all quotes in a document/text using regex?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to extract all the quotations that appear inside of a document using python regex.

I have code as follows, but it is not working:

```
import re
hand = open('citi.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('(?:"(.*?)")', line):
        print line
```

Comment: Please define "is not working".  What problem, exactly, do you observe?  This code should print every line which has at least two occurrences of `'"'` -- is that **not** what you want?  Give a small example of what you want and what you're getting, please (with a toy-sized `city.txt` of, say, three smallish lines).

Comment: I know you said regex but...how about open('citi.txt').read().replace('"', '')?

Comment: change your if statement to `print re.search(r'(?:"(.*?)")', line).group(1)`

Comment: Here's a snippet from the file:                                                                Citibank, N.A. (“CBNA”) will, on or after the date hereof, provide to HighArc Capital Management, L.P. (“Counterparty”) certain information in respect of the potential sale of all or a portion of certain debt (the “Loan”) encumbering interests in Shore Club in Miami, FL (the “Information” and any such transaction, the “Transaction”).   -----> what I want to extract is :   Transaction + Information + Loan + Counterparty + CBNA

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.findall('(?:"(.*?)")', line)` to extract only the quoted text from the line rather than printing the whole line, even if there are more than one occurences per line. Your code can be modified as follows:

```
import re

# This will make sure citi.txt is properly closed after opening it.
# infl.read() will read the whole file as single string, so no need to loop
with open('citi.txt', 'r') as infl:
    hand = infl.read()

# And look for occurences of your string
match = re.findall('(?:"(.*?)")', hand)
if match:
    print match
```

e.g. if `line == 'This is "a sample" line with "two quoted" substrings'`, this code will print `['a sample', 'two quoted']`

**Edit: Adapted to unicode**

It seems that your quotes are unicode characters. Note the subtle differences between ", “, ” (that I haven't spotted initially either).

My original answer and your code example are based on ASCII strings, but you will need a regex string like this:

```
match = re.findall(u'(?:\u201c(.*?)\u201d)', hand)
```

Explanation: `\u201c` is for *left double quote* and `\u201d` for *right double quote*, the `u` marks the string as Unicode.

This now works with the excerpt you have provided.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.  To be clear, I'm trying to find and display EVERYTHING that is quoted, i.e., every single "instance" of a quotation in the text.

Comment: It returned nothing.  Could the problem be related to the fact that the quoted text appears inside of parentheses (the "quoted text"), like so?  How would you deal with the parentheses?  Here's a full excerpt (and Thank you! :)) Citibank, N.A. (“CBNA”) will, on or after the date hereof, provide to HighArc Capital Management, L.P. (“Counterparty”) certain information in respect of the potential sale of all or a portion of certain debt (the “Loan”) encumbering interests in Shore Club in Miami, FL (the “Information” and any such transaction, the “Transaction”). @Geotob